# Removing the sum of the selected elements in JComboBox-es from the last JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm new to Java in general and just started studying UI and working on a personal project that will require me to have a `JTable` that will contain 4 `JComboBox` objects in every row.

Each `JComboBox` will contain values from 0 to 10. What I'm trying to achieve here is to add up the selected values from the first 3 `JComboBox`es, subtract 10, and remove the result from the last `JComboBox` menu. For example:

```
itemToRemove = ((JComboBox1Value + JComboBox2Value + JComboBox3Value) - 10)
```

If the value of `itemToRemove` falls between `-10` to `10`, then remove it from the 4th `JComboBox` ignoring the positive or negative sign.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private String[] coulmnsNames;
    private Object[][] rowData;
    private String[] boxData;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private MyTableCellEditor editor;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MyFrame() {
        setSize(1000, 500); // sets the size of the frame
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // positions the frame in the center of the
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        coulmnsNames = new String[]{"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"};
        rowData = new Object[][]{{"Row1"}, {"Row2"}, {"Row3"}};
        boxData = new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
        editor = new MyTableCellEditor(boxData);
        model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, coulmnsNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

        for(int col = 0; col < coulmnsNames.length; col++){
            TableColumn tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col);
            if(col!= 0){
                tc.setCellEditor(editor);
            }
        }
        contentPane.add(scroll);
    }

}
```

And here is the `MyTableCellEditor` class:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

/**
 * @author Ahmed Abouelela, A00951769
 * @version Dec 14, 2015 8:02:08 AM
 */
public class MyTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements
        TableCellEditor {

    private JComboBox<Object> menu;
    private String[] masterValues;
    private List<Integer> vals;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int value = 0;

    public MyTableCellEditor(String[] masterValues) {

        this.menu = new JComboBox<Object>();
        this.masterValues = masterValues;
        vals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see javax.swing.CellEditor#getCellEditorValue()
     */
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return menu.getSelectedItem();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor#getTableCellEditorComponent(javax.swing
     * .JTable, java.lang.Object, boolean, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel<Object> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>(
                masterValues);

        for (int tRow = 0; tRow < table.getRowCount(); tRow++) {

                    if(tRow != row){
                        String str = (String) table.getValueAt(tRow, column);
                        model.removeElement(str);
                }
        }
        menu.setModel(model);
        menu.setSelectedItem(value);
        return menu;
    }
}
```

I apologize for my English and the way I'm posting, this is my first time to ask a question on Stack Overflow. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you guys.

Comment: (1) "*remove the product*" What product? You are not multiplying anything. (2) "*if the value of `itemToRemove` falls between `-10` to `10`*" and what if not? (3) What is the problem / question?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the value for a row and remove it if it is not too high. If you add the following code to the `MyTableCellEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent` method, I think it should work:

```
// [existing code]

int result = -10;
for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex < 4; columnIndex++) {
    final String cellValue = (String) table.getValueAt(row, columnIndex);
    if (cellValue != null) {
        result += Integer.parseInt(cellValue);
    }
}
result = Math.abs(result);

if (result <= 10) {
    model.removeElement(Integer.toString(result));
    System.out.println("Removed item " + result);
}

// [existing code]
```

There is some code in the existing method that is already modifying the combo box `model`: the values that are chosen for other rows in the same column are removed. You could add the code above to the existing code (or perhaps replace it).